# Why Invoke BeginInvoke & EndInvoke are virtual when internal class is sealed?

Tags: c#, delegates

I've observed that Whenever the compiler encountered a delegate declaration like the following:

`public delegate string StringOperation(string myString);`

Then the compiler is generating the following code:

```
public sealed class StringOperation: System.MulticastDelegate  
{  
   public StringOperation (object target, int method);  
   public virtual void Invoke(string myString);  
   public virtual IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(string myString,  
   AsyncCallback callback, object obj);  
   public virtual void EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result);  
}
```

My question is, why would it generate `virtual` methods when the class itself is a `sealed` class?

There is no point of creating `virtual` methods as we cannot `override` them right?

Comment: How did you obtain that code?

Comment: I've read in the following article: [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca6c61/delegate-in-C-Sharp/) . and when i check in the ildasm, it shows the same concept of sealed & virtual.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this piece of the framework, but Reflector gives this as the definition of `BeginInvoke`:

```
[MethodImpl(0, MethodCodeType=MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(string myString, AsyncCallback callback, object @object);
```

My eye was drawn to the `MethodImpl` attribute. `MethodCodeType.Runtime` means:

> Specifies that the method implementation is provided by the runtime.

So I guess it is `virtual` because the runtime will override its functionality. And the runtime could easily pass the `sealed` class.

Comment: Ohh okay, I'm getting it. Thanks man..!